# HTACCESS Remove Slug Not Working

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have custom post type on my wordpress site. And it has slug "dizi"
so url's are like that now
site.com/dizi/mypost
i want to remove dizi slug so they will be
site.com/mypost
I tried lots of wordpress function and none of them work and then i try htaccess but it is not working also.
Here is my htacess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^dizi/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

With this code i can't see any effect.I m sure there is url conflict because i just installed wordpress and i have only 1 post.

Comment: Have you got `AllowOverride` set for the parent vhost, in httpd.conf? If not, `.htaccess` files won't have any effect.

Comment: I don't know if it is setted i'm using shared hosting i will send a ticket

Comment: Just put some garbage in a `.htaccess` file and see if you get a 500 error.

Comment: I cleaned file and put random letters on it. I'm taking 404 error every sub page except /wp-admin and homepage

Comment: maybe the last line should be: RewriteRule ^/dizi/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R] I mean instead of "^dizi" start with "^/dizi"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the order of the lines. /index should be the last, the special patterns should be caught before:

```
RewriteRule ^dizi/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: After i did that my css not loaded and rewrite was working but it was loading homepage under correct url

Comment: Does your css path also start with dizi/ ?

Comment: my domain is dizipi so it containts dizi word can it match with pattern ?

Comment: No, you only mats the path here

Comment: You can have a look yourself site adress is dizipi.com

Comment: /public_html/wp-content/themes/tema/style.css is my css path

Comment: My mistake, I didn't see that the 3 lines have to stay together

Comment: Now rewriting working but still loads homepage on it brobably a wordpress problem but i have no idea

Comment: Yes, it's because wordpress is configured in a way that it looks for that dizi/ at the beginning. Maybe you should open another question specific to the wordpress problem

Comment: Thanks i'm marking as answered because htaccess problem solved.